# who can create site collection administrator?

Tags: permissions

I am a site collection administrator. Can I give that role to a user, or does it have to be done through Central Admin or something more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

Site Settings -> In Users and Permissions section : Site Collection Administrators

If you are in a subsite, go to Top Level Site Settings, then Site Collection Administrators